# How do I create a matlab 201X 201 matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

How do I create a 201x 201 matrix with all odd rows alternating as 3,1,3 and the even rows alternating as 1,2,1,2. I tried using a random number generator, a for loop, and am thinking about using the find command. I am trying to generate a matrix, but I have recieved error messages.

Comment: can you provide some information about the errors? A nested for loop should have no problem whatsoever generating that matrix

Comment: also if you want to generate a specified matrix, why would you even attempt a random number generator or find command? Can you clarify this problem? What I envision you want: [3 1 3 1...;1 2 1 2...;3 1....]

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. How do I specify that this continues for 201 rows and 201 columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you mean correctly, then the Kronecker product (`kron`) is the simplest way to achieve this:

```
A = kron( ones(101), [3 1; 1 2]);
A = A(1:201, 1:201);
```

The first command creates a 202x202 matrix according to your requirements, and the second command chops 1 row and 1 column off to conform to the 201x201 size specification.

Answer (score 3):

Use [repmat](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/repmat.html) and matrix concatenating:

```
rowodd =[repmat([3 1],1,100) 3];
roweven=[repmat([1 2],1,100) 1];

mat = [repmat([rowodd;roweven],100,1) ; rowodd];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also create the matrix by using `meshgrid` and a mathematical function that gives you the desired result matrix:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:201, 1:201);
Matrix = 2*mod(X,2) - 2*mod(Y+1,2) + 3*(mod(X+1,2).*mod(Y+1,2)) + 1;
```